# Excel dashboard using slicers when cell contains multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, slicers

I have a problem with creating the dashboard in excel. My data is about sales, clients, meetings.  One of the columns contains the type of transaction (for example: AAA, BBB etc). Usually for each row there is one type of transaction, but in some cases there are two or even three.

So for example it could look like this:

| Invoice | Type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Invoice_1 | AAA | 100$ |
| Invoice_2 | BBB | 200$ |
| Invoice_3 | AAA, BBB | 500$ |

I wanna create a dashboard with slicers and Pivotcharts, but when I do slicer based on the Column "Type" it gives me the three values to choose from: AAA; BBB; AAA, BBB.

Is there a way around this problem? So Excel could identify this data as simply AAA or BBB (to check if the cell contains a given type of transaction separated by comma?

Answer (score 1):

An Excel slicer shows all values of the column. You have three distinct values, so that's what the slicer shows. Excel doesn't magically know that in your world, "AAA, BBB" means "both AAA and BBB". It just sees the text for its face value.

If you want to show only two values in the slicer, then you need to clean up your data data to contain only two values.

That may involve breaking down data rows with several types in to several rows, each with just one type value.

Since we don't know your data and the business logic or process that leads to the data, it is not possible to tell you exactly how to do that.